# How to save video into file which i get from POST request method?

Tags: python, flask, post, http-post

I am writing a Python backend for an Android app with Flask. I get video from POST method (when I do this: `print(request.files['video'].read())` I get "d3\xb9}\xff\x04\xa4M\xef\x8fS\xc1\xf0\x9e:|ge\x1cfO\xc1\x11ry\x0b\xea\xd1\x82\xf2\xa9-H..."). I can convert it to numpy array by doing this `np.frombuffer(request.files['video'].read(), np.uint8)`, but I don't know what to do next to save video to file in mp4 format. Can you please help me?

Comment: Does the video come in one piece (small video), or are you streaming it (large video)?

Comment: @simic0de in one piece, videos will be around 20-30 sec

Comment: Welcome to SO! I invite you to take the tour and visit our help center to learn more about the site and its guidelines. Good first post, by the way. :) @Polina

Answer (score 1):

No need for you to read the file, if you just want to save the video as a file.

You can use the method provided by Flask's documentation. It provides a guideline on how to handle files. Link is here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Or you can use an extension called "Flask-Uploads", which enable you to handle file uploading in a convenient way.

Here is an example:

```py
from flask_uploads import UploadSet
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

media = UploadSet('media', ('mp4')) # Create an upload set that only allow mp4 file
....
@app.route('/upload/', methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    if "video" in request.files:
        video = request.files["video"]
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename) # Secure the filename to prevent some kinds of attack
        media.save(video, name=filename)
        # Video saved
```

For detailed documentation of Flask-Uploads, check it out here: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/